# Chrome Theme Change Address Background

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-theme

I'm working on a Google Chrome Theme, but I can't figure out how to change the main address bar background and text color.

I know this question has been asked in different forms before, and people say it's a system level issue. But it seems odd that when you open an incognito mode window, the address bar is dark grey. Doesn't that suggest that it's controlled on an application basis not determined by the system?

Also of note, I've found that you can change the address bar on Android chrome by using the  tag. I'm guessing that this functionality is disabled for macOS Chrome (especially since Chrome themes are JSON), but it seems to hint at built-in functionality.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: No [such setting](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/themes/theme_properties.h)

Comment: Do you know how Chrome changes the address bar color in incognito mode?

Comment: It's hard-coded. You can browse the source code of chromium yourself.